# How can I send a large byte from JAVA socket to C# socket

Tags: java, c#, sockets

When i send a large byte from JAVA socket to C# socket, an error message

> "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write
>   error"

has been prompted.

it works fine when the byte is small (eg. "Hello world.").

how can i send a large byte from JAVA socket to C# socket?
Also, how can i convert the JAVA byte into C# byte in the JAVA code?

Thanks.

Following is my source code:

JAVA Code:

```
byte[] decryptedAttachmentByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(decryptedAttachment);
OutputStream os = m_socket.getOutputStream();
int toSendLen = toSendBytes.length;
byte[] toSendLenBytes = new byte[4];

toSendLenBytes[0] = (byte)(toSendLen & 0xff);
toSendLenBytes[1] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 8) & 0xff);
toSendLenBytes[2] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 16) & 0xff);
toSendLenBytes[3] = (byte)((toSendLen >> 24) & 0xff);

os.write(toSendLenBytes);
os.write(toSendBytes); << Exception here
```

C# Code

```
byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);
```

Comment: 1.First you have to check if there is a limit on the maximum buffer size or not, and if there is any , then you should divide the sent message to multiple fragments and combine them back at the receiver side, or use some type of encoding to minimize the size of the message. 2. The bytes of message should be the same in C# and Java, if the encoding used is the same.

Comment: use XML or JSON